# python: check if substring is in tuple of strings

Tags: python, substring, tuples

Which is the most elegant way to check if there is an occurrence of several substrings in a tuple of strings?

```
tuple = ('first-second', 'second-third', 'third-first') 
substr1 = 'first' 
substr2 = 'second' 
substr3 = 'third'
#if substr1 in tuple and substr2 in tuple and substr3 in tuple:
#    should return True
```

Comment: Don't use `tuple` this is a python keyword.

Comment: @AChampion It's not a keyword. If it were, assigning to it wouldn't even work.

Comment: `tuple` is a builtin - thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the tuple for each of the substrings, so using `any` and `all`:

```
all(any(substr in s for s in data) for substr in ['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

Comment: Nice, I like this! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

```
any(substr in str_ for str_ in tuple_)
```

You can start with that and look at `all()` as well.

Comment: Haha it was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: still i guess another str is there

Comment: so `any(substr1 in str for str in tuple_) and any(substr2 in str for str in tuple_) and any(substr3 in str for str in tuple_)` is the preferable way to do this?

Comment: You can use an all() to do them all in one go instead of using and explicitly. Like AChampion showed below.

Comment: @AChampion I'd say the `str` was far less bad, since it was confined to just that small simple generator. (I'd still not do it, though.)